# Could not wait for server fd - select (11: Resource temporarily unavailable) [IP: 148.251.160.247 443]

Tags: apt, updates

i try to run `sudo apt update` but i get flowing error

```
Hit:1 http://ir.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal InRelease
Hit:2 http://ir.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates InRelease                                                                                         
Hit:3 http://ir.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports InRelease                                                                                                                      
Hit:4 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/php/ubuntu focal InRelease                                                                                                                                           
Get:5 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security InRelease [114 kB]                                                                                                                 
Err:6 https://dl.bintray.com/rabbitmq-erlang/debian focal InRelease                                                                                                            
  502  Bad Gateway [IP: 142.54.189.106 443]
Ign:7 https://packagecloud.io/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-server/ubuntu focal InRelease                                                                                                                              
Ign:8 https://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease                                  
Err:9 https://packagecloud.io/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-server/ubuntu focal Release                    
  Could not wait for server fd - select (11: Resource temporarily unavailable) [IP: 148.251.160.247 443]
Err:10 https://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable Release                                   
  Could not wait for server fd - select (11: Resource temporarily unavailable) [IP: 74.91.29.203 443]
Reading package lists... Done                 
E: The repository 'https://packagecloud.io/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-server/ubuntu focal Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'https://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable Release' no longer has a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

this is my source.list

```
# deb cdrom:[Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS _Focal Fossa_ - Release amd64 (20220223)]/ focal main restricted

# See http://help.ubuntu.com/community/UpgradeNotes for how to upgrade to
# newer versions of the distribution.
deb http://ir.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal main restricted
# deb-src http://ir.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal main restricted

## Major bug fix updates produced after the final release of the
## distribution.
deb http://ir.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal-updates main restricted
# deb-src http://ir.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal-updates main restricted

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu
## team. Also, please note that software in universe WILL NOT receive any
## review or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://ir.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal universe
# deb-src http://ir.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal universe
deb http://ir.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal-updates universe
# deb-src http://ir.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal-updates universe

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu 
## team, and may not be under a free licence. Please satisfy yourself as to 
## your rights to use the software. Also, please note that software in 
## multiverse WILL NOT receive any review or updates from the Ubuntu
## security team.
deb http://ir.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal multiverse
# deb-src http://ir.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal multiverse
deb http://ir.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal-updates multiverse
# deb-src http://ir.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal-updates multiverse

## N.B. software from this repository may not have been tested as
## extensively as that contained in the main release, although it includes
## newer versions of some applications which may provide useful features.
## Also, please note that software in backports WILL NOT receive any review
## or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://ir.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal-backports main restricted universe multiverse
# deb-src http://ir.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal-backports main restricted universe multiverse

## Uncomment the following two lines to add software from Canonical's
## 'partner' repository.
## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by Canonical and the
## respective vendors as a service to Ubuntu users.
# deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu focal partner
# deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu focal partner

deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security main restricted
# deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security main restricted
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security universe
# deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security universe
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security multiverse
# deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security multiverse

# This system was installed using small removable media
# (e.g. netinst, live or single CD). The matching "deb cdrom"
# entries were disabled at the end of the installation process.
# For information about how to configure apt package sources,
# see the sources.list(5) manual.
```

how can fix this?

Comment: Remove the 2 lines in the sources file that are the 2 errors in /etc/apt/sources.list

Comment: I updated question and add source.list to it.Which two lines do you mean?

Comment: I assume you are using shecan.ir to bypass repos that are blocking iran ip addresses. I think this error is raised since those repos have apparently mitigated shecan's bypassing methods.

Comment: In the meantime I advise against using google chrome since having non-updated google chrome can bear security risks. I assume you need the other repos for your work-related matters, I advise getting a europe vps and setting up proxy.

Comment: Also sometimes simply switching to a different ISP solves this issue, for instance switch to mobile hotspot from wifi.

Answer (score 0):

There are two problems.

1. You have added some repositories that doesn't exist or not working.

   https://dl.bintray.com/rabbitmq-erlang/debian focal
   https://packagecloud.io/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-server/ubuntu

It is set in some file(s) located in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d` directory.

2. Google repository is temporary unavailable for some reason. You can try again later. The repository looks correct to me.

It is a bit weird that at the same time 3 repositories including the Google one don't respond.

It can also be a network issue.

Comment: Ok all right, whats your idea for solve this problem?

Comment: If the repos really don't work, remove them.

Comment: i ran `autoremove` but it didn't work again and I get `Could not wait for server fd - select (11: Resource temporarily unavailable) [IP: 148.251.160.250 443]` at several

Comment: Running autoremove won't do anything. You need to remove the repo either using Software &  Updates, or remove the `.list` files.